# How to edit profile mybb forum

Tags: mybb

Making changes on this kind.

Specifically I would like to change this screen
[image]

I want to delete this field  "Joined" and make couple more corrections?

How hard is to do this I searched on options on forum but I think I need to edit css or php file?

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit :

Postbit template & Postbit_author_member